# Receiving random data bytes during STM32 CAN communication Rx

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus, nucleo, mcu

I'm using STM32F103RBT6 Nucleo board with CAN communication for my project. I use Microchip CAN Bus Analyzer(acts as a node) to transmit CAN data.

**Project Setup:**
CAN message flow from: CAN Bus Analyzer --> CAN Transceiver --> STM board.
I need to receive messages only from 0x581, 0x582, 0x583, 0x584, 0x4A1, 0x4A2, 0X4A3, 0X4A4 IDs. In order to achieve this I have applied filters for the same.

**Problem:**
In Keil's debugger mode, I'm able to see the CAN messages which are transmitted, getting received in 'RxData' properly. However when I try to send data of 4 bytes length, RxData data bytes from 1 to 4 gets filled with the exact same message that I transmit, but data bytes 5 to 8 also gets filled randomly (In ideal case, bytes 5 to 8 should all be zero). This problem happens only when I send data of byte length 4. I tried sending data bytes of varying length (other than 4), it worked just fine. The problem lies only whenever I try to send data byte of length 4.
I have attached my entire program code below. And attached screenshots of the issue. Please find below.

```
#include "main.h"

CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;

CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef TxHeader;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader;
CAN_FilterTypeDef sFilterConfig;

uint8_t RxData[8];
uint8_t TxData[8];
uint32_t TxMailbox;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN_Init(void);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    // Empty while.
  }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL12;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
{

  hcan.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan.Init.Prescaler = 2;
  hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_10TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
  hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
    
  uint16_t StdIdArray1 [4] = {0x581, 0x582, 0x583, 0x584};  // 0x58x ID Series 
  uint16_t StdIdArray2 [4] = {0x4A1, 0x4A2, 0x4A3, 0x4A4};  // 0x4Ax ID Series
    
  uint16_t mask, tmp, i, num;  
    
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 5;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;     // Mask Mode
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;    // 16 Bit

  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = StdIdArray1[0] << 5;      // Filter Id Low
    
  mask = 0x5ff;  
  
  num = sizeof (StdIdArray1)/sizeof (StdIdArray1[0]);  // Mask code
  for (i = 0; i <num; i ++)
  {  
    tmp = StdIdArray1[i]^(~StdIdArray1 [0]);  
    mask &= tmp;  
  }  
    
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = (mask << 5) | 0x10;   // Filter Mask Id Low

  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = StdIdArray2[0] << 5;     // Filter Id High
    
  mask = 0x4ff; 
  
  num = sizeof (StdIdArray2)/sizeof (StdIdArray2[0]);   // Mask code
  for (i = 0; i <num; i ++)
  {  
    tmp = StdIdArray2[i]^(~ StdIdArray2[0]);  
    mask &= tmp;  
  }  
    
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = (mask << 5) | 0x10;  // Filter Mask Id High
    
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;               // FIFO 0
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;  
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;
    
    if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan,&sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
        {
        Error_Handler();
        }
    
    if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
   {

        Error_Handler();
   }
    
  if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK)
   {
        Error_Handler();
   }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* Receive Callback. Get messages from the CAN bus analyzer */
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
{
    if (HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData) != HAL_OK)
    {
        
        Error_Handler();
    }
    if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(hcan, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

}

void Error_Handler(void)
{

}

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 

}
```

*Screenshots:*
*Case 1:*
ID= 581; DLC= 8;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPnt1.jpg)

*Case 2*:
ID = 581; DLC=6;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58EaA.jpg)

*Case 3:*
ID= 581; DLC=2;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhlO6.jpg)

**Case 4: (Issue)**
ID = 581; DLC=4;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2qrp.jpg)

**Case 5: (Issue)**
ID= 4A1; DLC=4;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IItGt.jpg)

This issue is only with data byte of length 4. It could be of great help if someone can help me resolve this!

Comment: You aren't sending the same CAN ID but different DLC + data at the same time though, right? Because that won't work.

Comment: As depicted in the cases 4 and 5, the CAN analyser signal DLC equal to 4. So just discard the other bytes value.  I would advice you to try another CAN analyser or another node and check if the problem persits. For me i suspect an issue in Microship analyser perhaps you can post on their support forum.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sending the same CAN ID but different DLC + data not at the same time. Different byte streams are send at different time intervals. Only in case 4 and 5 I've used a different CAN ID. Please refer to my screenshots.

Comment: @SOFuser As u can see in case 4 and 5 screenshots, my RxData[0 -3] gets filled exactly the data that I send from my CAN analyzer, but my RxData[4-7] gets randomly filled every time. And this happens only if I try to send a DLC of 4. I've two Microchip Can bus analyzer and I've tested it on both and the problem still persists. :(

Comment: Check how long a CAN frame you get with a scope. If the size varies as expected but your listener keeps presenting garbage, then the problem is the listener. (Just set all data to 0xAA 0xAA... Then there will be no stuffing and the frame will grow/shrink with exactly the amount of bit lengths that the change in data gave.)

Comment: @Heisenberg7 That's why I advised to post on Microchip's forums: It is not logic to have a DLC = 4 and corrupted data, bytes 4-7 should not have been read. Before that, you need to test with another node which is not Microchip's Analyser. and in the Rx node program make sure to set the Rw buffer to zeroes before receiving. If the data is not corrupted then it's an analyser issue.

Comment: @Lundin by scope u mean oscilloscope?

Comment: @SOFuser I tested with another node instead of Microchip's analyzer, I'm still facing the issue. So I think the analyzer is working fine, right? There is problem somewhere o.0

Comment: @Heisenberg7 Aye, ye olde electron cannon.

Comment: @Heisenberg7, So you need to post your part of code that is sending the data.

Comment: @Heisenberg7 Did you resolve your problem? I have the same problem